# Unable to consistenly show embed pdf on browser

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, pdf

I'm using Django to send a PDF to my frontend, where the file is displayed embedded in the HTML. The problem I'm facing is that the PDF viewer is showing the correct number of pages for the file, but all the pages are blank. For some files, the content is displayed correctly, but for others, only blank pages are visible.

This is the code I'm using on my backend:

```
import base64
with open(new_path, 'rb') as file:
    archivo_pdf = file.read()
    archivo_pdf = base64.b64encode(archivo_pdf).decode('utf-8')

respuesta_json = {
    'archivo_pdf': archivo_pdf,
    'fecha': new_fecha
}

return JsonResponse(respuesta_json)
```

And this is the code I'm using on the frontend to process the file:

```
var contenidoPDF = atob(response.archivo_pdf)
var blob = new Blob([contenidoPDF], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
$('#pdf-container').html('<object data="' + url + '" type="application/pdf" width="1100" height="800"><embed src="' + url + '" type="application/pdf"></object>');
```

I tried using PyPDF2 to return the file since I read that it might help, but it didn't work. I also tried changing the "decode" method used, but it still doesn't work. Can someone give me some guidance on what I might be doing wrong?

Image of the problem:

[image]